# Passing Data TableViewController to ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an app and exploring the SWIFT language. I gave come across this point (check code below) and i am stuck. Help From you all will be much appreciated.

i have a `TableViewController` which displays values of cities from JSON and the same data is to be displayed on `DetailsViewController` as details.
I am passing these json data through dictionaries. 
Where I am stuck!!!
The data from dict(dictinary 1 in tableviewcontroller) is passed to dict2(dictionary 2 in detailsviewcontroller) but its not displayed on the labels in detailsviewcontroller. Have a look at the code.

```
    TableViewController 

      override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { 

      print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

        let d = self.tempArray[indexPath.row]
        self.dict ["fcodeName"] = d.fcodename
        self.dict ["toponymName"] = d.toponyname
        self.dict ["countrycode"] = d.countrycode
        self.dict ["fcl"] = d.fcl
        self.dict ["fclName"] = d.fclname
        self.dict ["name"] = d.name
        self.dict ["wikipedia"] = d.wikipedia
        self.dict ["lng"] = d.lng
        self.dict ["fcode"] = d.fcode
        self.dict ["geonameId"] = d.geonameid
        self.dict ["lat"] = d.lat
        self.dict ["population"] = d.population
        print("Dictionary \(self.dict)")


    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if (segue.identifier == "show") {
            print("Dictionary \(self.dict)")

            let DetailsView = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsViewController
            DetailsView.dict2 = self.dict



        }

    }

}
```

DetailsViewController

```
    import UIKit

    class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {

    var dict2 = [String : AnyObject]()

    @IBOutlet var lblName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var lblFcodeName: UILabel! 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    self.lblTopName.text = self.dict2["toponymName"]?.stringValue
        self.lblFcodeName.text = self.dict2["fcodeName"]?.stringValue
        print("Dictionary 2 \(self.dict2)")
    }
```

P.S. In Console i can see the Dictinary 2 empty at first and loaded after the first dictionary loads second `TableViewController` cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD:** `@IBOutlet var lblName: UILabel!` and `self.lblTopName.text` different variables.

Also add this:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("show", sender: tableView)
tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
```

after

```
self.dict ["population"] = d.population
print("Dictionary \(self.dict)")
```

Comment: Um... I see two places that says `print("Dictionary \(self.dict)")`. which one do you mean? The first one? (I think)

Comment: Not Working @aaisataev ... instead its showing animation 2 times on cell click

Comment: if twice, need to delete `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("show", sender: tableView)`

Comment: what if do all stuff from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` except `tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)` in `prepareForSegue` before `let DetailsView = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsViewController`?

Comment: performSegueWithIdentifier("show", sender: self) this worked. thank You @aaisataev